# What is RequestFinalizeOnShutdown method

Tags: c#

I have heard on multiple occasions about `RequestFinalizeOnShutdown` method. Last time I heard about it in Build 2014.

All I can get is a short description

> When an application terminates, some objects are still reachable and will not have their Finalize method called. This can happen if background threads are using the objects or if objects are created during application shutdown or AppDomain unloading. In addition, by default, Finalize methods are not called for unreachable objects when an application exits so that the application may terminate quickly. Of course, all operating system resources will be reclaimed, but any objects in the managed heap are not able to clean up gracefully. You can change this default behavior by calling the System.GC type's RequestFinalizeOnShutdown method. However, you should use this method with care since calling it means that your type is controlling a policy for the entire application.

from page 502 of The Power of C# By Rajeev A. Parida book, some random posts from the internet [[1]](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~milani/dotnetfaq.htm),  [[2]](https://alexatnet.com/articles/net-memory-management-and-garbage-collector) and [2 mysterious links](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=RequestFinalizeOnShutdown%20&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4) on MSDN that actually lead nowhere. And most interestingly this method has never been mentioned on StackOverflow.

What is this method? Has it been renamed? Is the behavior described in the book correct?

Comment: It looks like it was introduced in a beta of one of the frameworks and subsequently removed (MS does this a lot it seems, some nice features of C# 6 didn't make it from preview to release). I think the closest equivalent is `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` which suspends the current thread until any pending finalizers are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to be accurate, this is mostly lost in the fog of time, but this method appears to go back to late January 2001 when .NET 1.0 beta 1 was released.  Many bloggers and book authors were interested in it and wrote about the details of garbage collection.  Looks like the policy back in that early version was to *not* finalize objects at program shutdown.  And calling GC.RequestFinalizeOnShutdown() changed this.

A rather flawed idea and it was removed again from beta 2.  But, somewhat inevitably, the bloggers and book authors did not update their musings, causing this method to not be forgotten like it should.

You need to ignore this, finalizers run at shutdown and there isn't any way to reconfigure that.  A timeout ensures that it won't get stuck, 2 seconds by default.